# How can I reinstall htmlpublisher-wrapper.html at Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I accidentally removed the file `htmlpublisher-wrapper.html`.

I have the HTML Publisher plugin installed.

How can I get this file back?
Can I copy paste its content from somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the lack of details in your question, I assume you're talking about the `htmlpublisher-wrapper.html` file that is generated and stored in `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job_name>/​htmlreports/<report_name>/htmlpublisher-wrapper.html`, for Jenkins builds that have the HTML Publisher plugin enabled.

The easiest thing to do would be to just build the job again, which will cause the HTML report wrapper file to be generated again.

Otherwise, you could copy the file from another job that uses the HTML Publisher plugin and update the job and report names in the HTML.

You could also take the file from a backup.

Finally, you could create the file yourself by taking the `header.html` and the `footer.html` files from the [plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/htmlpublisher-plugin/tree/htmlpublisher-1.11/src/main/resources/htmlpublisher/HtmlPublisher), and putting the original content in the middle, which should look similar to this:

```
<li id="tab1" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab1');" value="index.html">index</li>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("hudson_link").innerHTML="Back to [job_name]";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("hudson_link").href="http://[jenkins_url]/job/[job_name]/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("zip_link").href="*zip*/[report_name].zip";</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. I am new to Jenkins and I am trying to configure a fresh project and so another job is not available (that uses HTML Publisher plugin)
I was having some issue with HTML reports so I changed the directory name at "HTML directory to archive" and also the "Index page[s]"
Now when I run the build again, and check the HTML report, I get this error message:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTVDev_VS_APITests/htmlreports/HTML_Report/htmlpublisher-wrapper.html (No such file or directory)
This is somehow still pointing to the old path in configuration.

Comment: I tried restarting Jenkins and reinstalling the HTML Publisher plugin. How can I change the path now?

Comment: Are you clicking on the "HTML Reports" link on the job page? Or visiting the URL directly? If you've done a new build, and it was successful, clicking on the link should show the correct report. If all else fails, just delete the `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTVDev_VS_APITests/htmlreports/` directory and start another build.